# Navigate to sub screen from everywhere

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm facing an issue. I want to find a single way to go a to specific sub screen from everywhere (from every stack). I need this to handle navigation on notification selection.
So the doc says, if i want to reach a sub screen, i have to proceed like this:

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
     routeName: 'Profile',
     params: {},
     action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SubProfileRoute' 
   }),
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)  // (1)
```

This works for me only if i'm outside the "Profile" Stack. But if i'm in the profile stack the navigation stucks at the initial screen on the Profile Stack.

So I have 2 questions :
- can we use the method (1) to move throughout the same stack ?
- Is there a way to know which stack the user is currently in ?
*this.props.navigation.state*  doesn't help (because I want the info in a listener located at a specific screen)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of answering your questions, I am going to suggest you an easy alternative. It is to use react-native-router-flux. It is very simple to use and addresses your questions above with very simple codes. After installing the module, add the following to you App.js file:

```
import { Router, Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Home from 'homeLocation';
import AnotherPage from 'anotherPageLocation';

const onBackPress = () => {
    if (Actions.state.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    Actions.pop()
    return true
};
const Routes = () => (
   <Router navigationBarStyle={{// your style}} backAndroidHandler={onBackPress}
      titleStyle = {{// your style}} navBarButtonColor = {"lightgrey"}>
      <Scene key = "root">
         <Scene key = "Home" component = {Home} title = "homePageTitle" initial = {true}/>
         <Scene key = "AnotherPage" component = {AnotherPage} title = "pageTitle" />
        // ...other scenes
      </Scene>
   </Router>
)
export default Routes;
```

Then, if you want to go to home page from any page, just write `Actions.Home()` or if you want to go to 'AnotherPage' just write `Actions.AnotherPage()`. If you want to get in what page that you are currently in, get it from `const currentpage = Actions.currentScene();`.It return the name of the current scene. For more info, refer this [page](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md).